# How to create a correct filter string with OR and AND operators for django?

Tags: vue.js, django-rest-framework

My app has a frontend on vue.js and backend on django rest framework. I need to do a filter string on vue which should do something like this:

```
((status=closed) | (status=canceled)) & (priority=middle)
```

but got an error as a response

> ["Invalid querystring operator. Matched: ') & '."]

After encoding my string looks like this:

```
?filters=((status%3D%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82)%20%7C%20(status%3D%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD))%20%26%20(priority%3D%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)
```

which corresponds to

```
?filters=((status=closed)|(status=canceled))&(priority=middle)
```

How should look a correct filter string for django?

I have no problem if statement includes only `|` or only `&`. For example filter string like this one works perfect:

```
?filters=(status%3D%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82)%20%7C%20(status%3D%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD)
```

a.k.a. `?filters=(status=closed)|(status=canceled)`. But if i add an `&` after it and additional brackets to specify the order of conditions calculation it fails with an error.

I also tried to reduce usage of brackets and had string like this (as experiment):

```
?filters=(status%3D%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%20%7C%20status%3D%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD)
```

a.k.a. `?filters=(status=closed | status=canceled)`. This one doesn't work - get neither error nor the data.

I need to have a mixed results in my case: both statuses (closed and canceled) and priority=middle, but a string format isn't correct. Please explain, which format would be Ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't look like a very uri friendly syntax you're trying to use there.

Try doing this instead:

```
?status[]=closed&status[]=cancelled&priority=middle
```

Then use `request.GET.getlist('status[]')` to get back the list and use the values for logical OR queryset filtering:

```
qs = qs.filter(status__in=request.GET.getlist('status[]', [])
```

and then add any additional filtering which works as logical AND.

If you're using axios, it should automatically format js `status` url param into proper format.

Comment: thank a lot!
`__in` statement was the key to my problem.
The filterstring (before encoding) in my case now looks like this: `(priority=middle) & (status__in=closed,canceled)`. Everything works correct.
Many thanks again!